# Javascript anonymous function adding object to it

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Can you explain what going on or some link to understand below code?

```
function createApplication() {
  var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  };

  mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype, false);
  mixin(app, proto, false);

  // expose the prototype that will get set on requests
  app.request = Object.create(req, {
    app: { configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, value: app }
  })

  // expose the prototype that will get set on responses
  app.response = Object.create(res, {
    app: { configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, value: app }
  })

  app.init();
  return app;
}
```

Here type of app is function but where other object is assigned and then after return how to access these object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little explanation:

`app` is named function:

```
var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  };
```

The `mixin` you see after are used to extend the properties on the original `app` object.

```
 mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype, false);
 mixin(app, proto, false);
```

Below, this code define some properties on `app.request` you can look at [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) for more infos.

> The Object.defineProperties() method defines new or modifies existing
>   properties directly on an object, returning the object.

In JS functions are objects so the can have their own properties (in this case `request`).

```
// expose the prototype that will get set on requests
  app.request = Object.create(req, {
    app: { configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, value: app }
  })

  // expose the prototype that will get set on responses
  app.response = Object.create(res, {
    app: { configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, value: app }
  })
```

The code initialize `app` object:

```
app.init();
```

Comment: I'm little bit confuse while you explain about getter and setter on name function and assigning object as getter and then how to access these object        values

Comment: thanks, I made an edit, basically In JS functions are objects so the can have their own properties (in this case `request`), so you can access it using app.request.

Comment: @SunilPatel You are welcome, I am glad it was useful. Please do not forget to accept or up vote my answer by clicking the tick/arrow up icons on its left side. Thanks for your collaboration.